# How much candy for walking Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the recent release of the Buddy system, players can now earn candy for "walking" their buddy Pokemon.

I have noticed that certain Pokemon require different distances. Has anyone found out how much candy you get for walking them a certain distance? Is the amount based on the distance? Do some get more than others or is it the same no matter the distance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](https://www.vg247.com/2016/09/14/pokemon-go-how-much-candy-each-pokemon-earns-as-a-buddy/),

> No matter the Pokemon, the required distance will only net you **one** candy.

The reason behind different distances is due to rarity of the Pokemon, not how much of a reward you will get.

**EDIT:**

There have been reports of users receiving two candies as a reward, but it is unknown what triggers this at the moment. Though, it does not seem intentional and is likely a bug.

Comment: Not entirely true, there is a chance to get 2 candies rarely. 
https://reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/52po1t

Comment: @Virusbomb that seems more like a glitch than the intended behavior, but I edited my answer to account for it.

Comment: There's no way to know if it's a glitch or intended random bonus, but as many people have reported it happening with no specific cause or malfunction my guess is it's a random chance. If it's a glitch it quickly will get worked out how and be exploited till it's patched.

Comment: @Virusbomb that may be. If you find any more information, feel free to update my answer

Comment: I could have sworn that their blog post said you could net two candies but I'm not finding it now. Either way, I don't think it's a bug but I can't find the official reference again either.

Comment: In the patch notes for the iOS version, it says that "the buddy Pokémon will earn a candy after a certain distance is travelled."